# What's the range on Mercy's Resurrect?

Tags: overwatch

Mercy's ultimate ability allows her to [revive dead teammates](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Resurrect), but I've noticed it definitely has a range restriction.

How close do I need to be to a corpse before Resurrect will work on it?

Comment: Are you looking for absolute numbers, or just for a way to tell how many teammates you'll resurrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever since Mercy's rework in 2017, Resurrect is now a single target ability that, according to the [patch notes](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20759166300), has a range of 5 meters.

Answer (score 6):

The range is listed as 15 meters on the patch notes from Feb 9. Couldn't find an active post at battle.net, so here is a [gosugamers link](http://www.gosugamers.net/overwatch/news/34297-patch-notes-the-return-of-the-overwatch-beta-breaths-new-life-into-forgotten-heroes)

Here is reddit post to give you a better idea of what a meter means in the game https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/48axy7/hero_ability_ranges/